# Azure Blueprints: Securestring parameters in assignment.json

Tags: azure, azure-cloud-services

It seems I have easy question, but I was not able to find any details about it anywhere:

How properly fill parameter in assignment.json file for Azure Blueprint, if this parameter has type: "securestring" in Blueprint.json file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest and secure way of doing this is to store this string in a KeyVault and use the secret reference in the blueprint artifact. For example:

```
"vmLocalAdminPassword": {
    "reference": {
        "keyVault": {
            "id": "/subscriptions/<subscriptionId>/resourceGroups/<resourceGroupName>/providers/Microsoft.KeyVault/vaults/<keyVaultName>"
        },
        "secretName": "vmLocalAdminPassword"
    }
}
```

Comment: Great. Glad to hear that!